# Add HTML(dropdown) in wordpress new page

Tags: html, css, xml, wordpress

How can i convert this to an wordpress new page. I tried to add it tru html but that didn't work. My dropdown is all mest up. Nothing seems to be good. Can anyone help me out please?
Are point me in the wright direction. Are show me a preview how i can fix this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Smoelenboek</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter.js"></script>
<script id="data" type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js" xmlData="data/raetexport.xml"></script>
</head>
<body>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
body { background-image:url('background-alert-ipad.jpg'); }
</style>

<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<div id="controller">
  <label class="control-label" for="searchinput"><Font color="#FFFFFF">Zoeken:</font>
    <input type="text" id="term">
  </label>

<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
  <label class="control-label"><Font color="#FFFFFF">Opties:</font>

    <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="none">Selecteer een optie</option>
      <option value="roepnaam">Voornaam</option>
      <option value="naamMedewerker">Achternaam</option>
      <option value="team">Team</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
  <input name="Zoeken" type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search">

</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want use this code as template for pages?

Comment: [Insert HTML Snippet](http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet) WordPress plugin is the solution, It Adds [HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) code to your pages and posts easily.

Comment: No i want to create a new page with the code in it.

Comment: then, make template pages in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct fix.

> Insert HTML Snippet WordPress plugin is the solution, It Adds HTML,
>   CSS and JavaScript code to your pages and posts easily. –  user3599534
>   1 hour ago

Thank you.